Redirect standard error hides the prompt of the read command
In a bash script, I redirect standard error to standard out in red color like so:
exec 2> >(sed $'s,.*,\e[38;5;9;82m&\e[m,'>&1)
However, this hides the prompt text of read:
read -p "prompt text " -n 1 -r
How to show the prompt text (possibly also in red color)?
Without the redirection, read works as expected.

Could you put the pieces (redirection, read command) together to a small script, so that we have a reproducible example?

You did not specify what OS you are on, but perhaps you could try >(stdbuf -o0 sed $'....'>&1) in your exec  cmd.

Another idea: Why don't you put the color escapes into prompt text?

This shoudl work :
#!/bin/bash

exec 2> >(sed $'s,.*,\e[38;5;9;82m&\e[m,'>&1)

date >&2

read -p "prompt text " -n 1 -r 2>/dev/tty

